# opposite of join -v?

Tags: text-processing, join

I have to do just the opposite of `join -v1 fileA fileB`, which says: print lines from fileA whose first fields do not match the first field of any line from fileB. Instead, I want to write the lines from fileA that *do* coincide (on their first fields) with lines from fileB.

I have tried to make `join -o 1.1 2.1 fileA fileB`, but this duplicates the lines that coincide, not write the line of the first file if same.

What is the easiest way?

Comment: `join fileA <(awk '{print $1}' fileB)`

Answer (score 2):

As Satō Katsura [commented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/301279/opposite-of-join-v#comment528755_301279), you could "trick" join into seeing only field 1 from fileB, then ask it to do a normal join; this prints the line from fileA and the (empty) remainder of the line in (the tricked) fileB:

```
join fileA <(awk '{print $1}' fileB)
```

Given input files of:

```
$ cat fileA
1 blah
2 foo
3 bar

$ cat fileB
3 barely
4 baz
5 qux
```

The resulting output is:

```
$ join fileA <(awk '{print $1}' fileB)
3 bar
```

[Wildcard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/135943/wildcard) pointed out that you can do this more directly (avoiding a process substitution), by piping awk's output to `join`:

```
awk '{print $1}' fileB | join fileA -
```

Answer (score 0):

If the two files are sorted, you can use `comm` like this to display the lines from `fileA` that are not in `fileB`:

```
comm -23 fileA fileB
```

Or did you also want the lines in `fileB` that are not in `fileA`?

Comment: Nope, `comm` works with whole lines, the OP wants to compare only the _first column_.

Comment: yes, that is right. thank you nevertheless

Comment: @Sato there's nothing in the question that refers to _fields_. Everything there says _lines_.

Comment: `join` works works with fields.